# Beeline error connecting to Hive2

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

This is my command on beeline
!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000

I got this error

Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: null (state=08S01,code=0)

How to solve it?

Comment: does your problem got solved..

Comment: im not sure, but when i tried this command i can connect to hive database
!connect jdbc:hive2://

Comment: could you please tell the value of this hive.server2.authentication property you have set in hive-site.xml is?

Answer (score 0):

Check if hive server is running in http mode or not.

Comment: how to do that? and if not how to run hive server in http mode?

Comment: Look configuration of hive-site.xml go throw  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the authentication like below commands to go to beeline.

It depends on hive.server2.authentication property value in hive-site.xml

Embedded Mode:

```
    !connect jdbc:hive2://
```

SASL Authentication:

if hive.server2.authentication=SASL then start beeline like below

```
        !connect jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>/<db>
```

NOSASL Authentication: hive.server2.authentication=NOSASL

```
        !connect jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>/<db>;auth=noSasl
```

HTTP Mode:hive.server2.authentication=HTTP

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>/<db>;hive.server2.transport.mode=http;
```

Just go to the property and start beeline depends on above value.It will Started without errors

Hope this really helpful for you